# Magento 2: How to get Order Wise Product's Manage Stock?

Tags: magento2, orders, inventory, magento2.1.5

Does Magento store Product Wise Manage Stock in DB?

Example: I have Product A : Qty: 10 with Manage Stock Yes

Order : 10 Qty

Now I have same product with Manage Stock No

Order : 5 Qty

Can I get Order wise Product A's when it's Manage Stock On/Off?

Output:

```
Order Id Product Id Manage Stock  Qty
1         1          1            10
2         1          0            5
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to find it in product options of order item

```
foreach($this->order->getAllItems() as $orderItem)
{
    $product_options    = $orderItem->getProductOptions();
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($product_options);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Not tested

Comment: Need to set hidden variable on Listing & Detail Page so it can store in `sales_order_item` field `product_options` & can check from that